# What's wrong with this SSI

Tags: ssi

I'm having trouble with SSI. It seems like I don't get to work the most basic command:

```
<!--#if expr="${title}" -->
<!--#echo var="title" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

I think it's obvious what I want to do and I can't find what's wrong with this piece of code. However SSI says [an error occurred while processing this directive].

The echo without the if block works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error:

Apache changed its syntax for SSI conditionals with Version 2.3 or something so now it has to look like that:

```
<!--#if expr='-n v("title")' -->
<!--#echo var="title" -->
<!--#endif -->
```